# UrlRewriteFilter is changing the Context-Path of my Web Application

Tags: url-rewriting, struts, tomcat

I have configured my web application (using Java Struts) under context /myapp - so my web-app URL starts with something like this http://test.mydomain.com/myapp/

I am using UrlRewriteFilter for providing clean URLs because of the multiple data models that we support. For example: Let's say I have 2 different types of data that I need to show my user - one if the list of hotels, other is the list of hospitals - depending on the type of user that logs in. However, both models are served by a common JSP page called commonView.jsp.

If user is interested in hotels, the URL would like
.../myapp/commonView.do?type=hotels

Similarly for hospitals, the URL would be
.../myapp/commonView.do?type=hospitals

Now, I don't want to show the user this weirdly looking name that reads 'commonView.do'. Hence, I have used UrlRewriteFilter to provide clean URLs. See below.

```
<rule match-type="regex">
    <from>^/view/([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)$</from>
    <to>/commonView.do?type=$1</to>
</rule>
```

The above rule displays http://test.mydomain.com/myapp/view/hotels in the browser but internally forwards the request to commonView.do?type=hotels. Similarly for hospitals.

Now my problem is, once this rule is executed my context-path starts to look like /myapp/view instead of just /myapp. And because of this, all my css, js, images etc are all gone - because now my web-app started to look for them under /myapp/view instead of just /myapp.

How do I solve this problem? How to avoid changing the context-path and still be able to use UrlRewriteFilter for providing clean URLs?

Answer (score 1):

just add this
`<BASE href="http://test.mydomain.com/myapp/">` in head section of your page

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule match-type="regex">
    <note>Serve these folders from the filesystem</note>
    <from>/(css|img|js|manifest)/(.*)</from>
    <to last="true">/$1/$2</to>
</rule>
```